# JS: Facebook Login: How can I call FB.logout() from different page?

Tags: javascript

I have a site build on Shopify so each page is an individual file with it's own code.
On the /login page, in addition to a normal login, I have a Facebook login option.
Upon successful Facebook login, I redirect the user to a /account route that has it's own code file.  I have a button for logout that calls a `logout` function --- in that function, I clear all the cookies related to a user being logged in but my issue is that the Facebook account is still logged in unless I call `FB.logout()`.  There is no instance of `FB` though on that page since it's a separate file.  Is there a way I can call that `FB.logout()` after redirecting to that route, where it's available?

ACCOUNT PAGE

```
function logout() {
   Cookies.remove("loginToken")
   window.location.href = "/login"

   // this redirects me to the login page but I need to call 
   // `FB.logout()` too which only exists on the Login page.  
}
```